# BLE disconnected with status 8, interval 36

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, android-ble

When trying to connect to Raspberry Pi BLE GATT server (using hardcoded BT address) from Android app, most of the times (not always) I'm getting:

```
D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=6 device=<ADDRESS>
D/BluetoothGatt: discoverServices() - device: <ADDRESS>
D/BluetoothGatt: onConnectionUpdated() - Device=<ADDRESS> interval=36 latency=0 timeout=500 status=8
D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=8 clientIf=6 device=<ADDRESS>
D/BluetoothGatt: close()
```

It seems like, right after connecting and starting the services discovery, the connection is lost with **interval=36, status=8**. What could be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Status code 8 just means that the connection timed out, usually because you go out of range or due to interference, or some hardware issue.

Comment: It's neither of the reasons - I'm testing it just next to the RPi and it happens on all of the smartphones I tested.

Comment: If it's not due to any of the reasons I explained, then it must be the firmware in the wifi-bt-combo chip in the RPi then that's buggy or not good enough, that it can't keep a stable BLE connection.

Comment: Is it possible that the Raspberry Pi is requesting new connection parameters (e.g new connection interval, supervision timeout, or slave latency) and because the Android app is not responding to this request you are getting the connection timeout issue?

Comment: I guess it is possible. If that's the case, how to solve it?

Comment: Failing to reply to a response will never result in a "connection timeout" error, but rather a specific error code will be sent instead. "Connection timeout" means exactly this, that the link layer air protocol didn't get any radio activity within the expected amount of time. However, if the remote link layer drops the connection due to a procedure timeout, it will terminate the link immediately and the remote device will get at "connection timeout".